# snakemake.remote.EGA: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics, snakemake

I want to use the snakemake utility (5.6.0) to use files stored on the EGA. First I wanted to try the code written in the official documentation, so I tried this:

```
import snakemake.remote.EGA as EGA

ega = EGA.RemoteProvider()

rule get_remote_file_ega:
   input:
       ega.remote("ega/dataset_id/foo.bam")
   output:
       "data/foo.bam"
   shell:
       "cp {input} {output}"
```

Before executing the script I created environment variables as necessary (EGA_USERNAME and EGA_PASSWORD).

Then I get the following error:

```
me:~/scripts$ snakemake -s test_ega.smk
Building DAG of jobs...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 551, in snakemake
    export_cwl=export_cwl)
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 433, in execute
    dag.init()
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 122, in init
    job = self.update([job], progress=progress)
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 603, in update
    progress=progress)
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 655, in update_
    missing_input = job.missing_input
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/jobs.py", line 396, in missing_input
    for f in self.input
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/jobs.py", line 397, in <genexpr>
    if not f.exists and not f in self.subworkflow_input)
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 208, in exists
    return self.exists_remote
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 119, in wrapper
    v = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 258, in exists_remote
    return self.remote_object.exists()
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/remote/EGA.py", line 173, in exists
    return self.parts.path in self.provider.get_files(self.parts.dataset)
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/remote/EGA.py", line 126, in get_files
    "data/metadata/datasets/{dataset}/files".format(dataset=dataset))
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/remote/EGA.py", line 96, in api_request
    headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer {}".format(self.token)
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/remote/EGA.py", line 77, in token
    self._login()
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/remote/EGA.py", line 45, in _login
    "client_id"    : self._client_id(),
  File "/home/puissant/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/remote/EGA.py", line 151, in _client_id
    return self._credentials("EGA_CLIENT_ID")
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

The part of the code involved is there (EGA.py line 151):

```
1   @classmethod
2   def _client_id(cls):
3         return self._credentials("EGA_CLIENT_ID")
```

Could the error come from a "self" instead of a "cls" on line 3? Because after changing it to "cls" the error moved to the next block, built in the same way. My understanding of python objects being limited, I hope I don't say great absurdities.

Have I forgotten any steps or misunderstood any of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you should be using `cls` (which presumably stands for 'class' here) rather than `self`. `self` is generally the name used for instances of classes i.e. objects. If you are using `self` elsewhere in the function, you need to switch them to `cls`.